# I tried running my python program in a mac os terminal but keep getting the feedback below after I have successfully installed Beautifulsoup4

Tags: python, macos, terminal, beautifulsoup

```
import urllib
from Beautifulsoup import*

url = raw_input('Enter - ')

html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = Beautifulsoup(html)

#Retrieve a list of the anchor tags
#Each tag is like a dictionary of HTML attributes

tags = soup('a')

for tag in tags:
    print tag.get('href', None)
```

that is the code am trying to run and below is the response i get from the terminal:

```
MacBook-Pro-3:documents frankline$ python ./parsing_html.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./parsing_html.py", line 2, in <module>
    from Beautifulsoup import*
ImportError: No module named Beautifulsoup
```

However, I have already installed Beautifulsoup as shown below:

```
MacBook-Pro-3:documents frankline$ sudo pip install Beautifulsoup4
The directory '/Users/frankline/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/frankline/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting Beautifulsoup4
  Downloading beautifulsoup4-4.5.3-py2-none-any.whl (85kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 92kB 151kB/s 
Installing collected packages: Beautifulsoup4
Successfully installed Beautifulsoup4-4.5.3
```

Please help me check the error

Answer (score 0):

Your import is wrong, Change `from Beautifulsoup import*` to:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

You might be looking for the documentation for Beautiful Soup 3. If so, you should know that Beautiful Soup 3 is no longer being developed, and that Beautiful Soup 4 is recommended for all new projects. If you want to learn about the differences between Beautiful Soup 3 and Beautiful Soup 4, see [Porting code to BS4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#porting-code-to-bs4).

Read [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#porting-code-to-bs4) for bs4 library

Comment: I tried the recommendation but still got the following error code.                                                       Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./parsing_html.py", line 2, in <module>
    from bs4 import Beautifulsoup
ImportError: cannot import name Beautifulsoup

Comment: @user3741351 Are you sure that you installed it at the right place? do you have several python version in your pc?

Comment: yes.  have bot python 2 and python 3. When i try it out in python3 it gives me the error below:  MacBook-Pro-3:documents frankline$ python3 parsing_html.py
  File "parsing_html.py", line 15
    print tag.get('href', None)
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

Please read [Document](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#making-the-soup):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open("index.html"))

soup = BeautifulSoup("<html>data</html>")
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you come across **ImportError**, first please try to import in python console first.

Pls use this import statement for using BeautifulSoup4.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```